# Can't scale, what's wrong?

Tags: modeling

I can't get anything to scale, no matter what object I click select and hit <kbd>S</kbd> -- nothing scales in my scene anymore. Did I inadvertently hit something and lock everything in place?

[image]?

[image]

Answer (score 11):

**Blender 2.91 Update:** Click on Options in the upper right hand of your viewport. *Under Transform > Affect Only, uncheck Locations*.

Refer to image below:

[image]

This can also be accessed by hovering over viewport and pressing <kbd>N</kbd> > *Click the Tool tab>Reveal Options>Reveal Transform>Uncheck Affect Only property Locations.*

Refer to image below:

[image]

---

**Previous answer from 2015:**

Oops. I had things locked with Manipulate Center Points.

[image: mpp]

Comment: Please add more detail to your answer so people know *how* to turn off 'Manipulate Center Points'.

Comment: I edited the question with an image.

Comment: Blender 2.9 on PC doesn't have that icon...any tips?

Comment: @BenC suggest add a new answer rather than editing this one.